# PHP routing with Codeigniter (Titles in URL for SEO)

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have some questions concering routing with Codeigniter. What I´m doing now is the following:

```
$route['articles/(:num)'] = 'articles/view/$1'; // $1 will contain an ID
```

This means that example.com/articles/123 will work perfectly and load an article with an ID of 123. But I also want to have the possiblilty to add the aticle´s title to the URL (for SEO). Example: example.com/articles/123/article-title

What I want is pretty much the same thing as Stack Overflow: stackoverflow.com/questions/123/the-title

How can I do that?

I´m also wondering how Stack Overflow works. If I go to stackoverflow/questions/111 the title will automatically be added to the url. Is that done with php redirect()?

Comment: have you tried: `$route['articles/(:num)/(:any)']` ? and when passing this third parameter, you have to replace the blank spaces with `-` and don't think there is a need for what was proposed by Christian Giupponi

Comment: @Daniel Yes, but I want the title to be optional, just like here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: But I think that will work, have you tested? I think that since the third parameter is `(:any)`

Comment: @Daniel Yes, (:any) is correct, but I get "Page not found" when not adding the title.

Comment: how will you define is the title is optional or not? I never tried to but maybe you can create two routers, one with `(:any)` and the other without it, who knows =) I do that with Laravel and works perfectly

Comment: @Daniel Try removing the title to this question in the URL and load the page, you will notice it works just as good without the title.

Comment: I did that, I know what you want to do. Have you tried creating the same router with different parameters? One with `(:any)` and the other without?

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! That works! Any idea how I add the title if it´s not there? (Just like Stack Overflow does.) Maybe they redirect the user with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done something similar in the past; I can't find it know but IIRC (it was months ago) You can use a route like you did, and also add a more specific one, like

```
$route['articles/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'articles/view/$1/$2';
$route['articles/(:num)'] = 'articles/view/$1';
```

As you can see, both map to the same method, which is kind of "overloaded"; you can make up for a missing parameter by using a default value:

```
function articles($id,$slug = FALSE) 
{ }
```

and simply ignore the second parameter  in your article retrieval.

As for adding the title you can:

1. have a "slug" field in your database, created when the article is saved. You can use the comfortable `url_title($title,'dash',TRUE)` function (in the url helper), which takes the `$title`, uses the `dash` as separator, and make it all lowercase;
2. use the above function and convert the title of the article (after you retrieved it from the database) "on-the-fly"; just check on the article() method if the 2nd parameter isn't false and you'll know if you need to create the slug or not;

As for how to show the slug even when using an url without it you can make, as you guessed, a redirect, but since both routes point to the same method it won't change anything for you.

Oh, uhm, beware of loops while calling the redirect, check carefully ;)

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how Stack Overflow does to automatically add the title if it was missing? PHP redirect() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a slug field into your table and complete it with the url you want to use as id.
Let me explain.

You have this table

```
id
title
slug
```

when you save an article into your db you can dinamically create a slug, for example:

```
id: 1
title: My first post
slug: 1-my-first-post
```

then you can use the slug (in this case 1-my-first-post) ad id for the page, you can call it:

```
www.example.com/articles/1-my-first-post
```

obviusly you need to handle it in your db slect

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It does not, however, answer any of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed on the comments.

You can create a route several times and with different parameters each, like:

```
$route['articles/(:num)/(:any)']
$route['articles/(:num)']
```

I would create a function with a redirect, adding or not the title to it.

Hope it helps.