# Error while redirecting in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to have my post title in my url, separated with dashes and I do that with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001824/6277870) and this is my code :

```
 public function post($post_id, $slug = ''){
    $data['post'] = $this->posts_model->get_post_by_id($post_id);
    if ($slug) {
        $get_title = $data['post']->post_slug;
        redirect('blog/' . $post_id . '/' . $get_title);
    }
    $this->load->view('pages/show-post', $data);
}
```

and these are my routes :

```
$route['blog/(:num)'] = 'blog/post/$1';
$route['blog/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'blog/post/$1/$2';
```

**Problem :** when I load my `example.com/blog/1` everything is ok, but when I load `example.com/blog/1/anything` my code redirect me to `example.com/blog/1/my-slug-from-database` successfully but page load failed and firefox show me `The page isn't redirecting properly` error.

How can I solve this problem ? Is there any problem in my code ?

Thanks for your helps !

Answer (score 2):

You access `example.com/blog/1/anything`, and redirected to `example.com/blog/1/my-slug-from-database`. Now in CI, you get to the same function, and then because `$slug` is true, you are redirected again to `example.com/blog/1/my-slug-from-database`. You have a redirection loop - that is what causing the The page isn't redirecting properly error.

You need a way to stop the redirection - as far as I can see from your code, check if `$slug === $get_title`, and if so - don't redirect. But it's really hard to know what to do, because I'm not sure what you attempt to do.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you really want is to prevent the url to show without a slug to improve the link quality and for SEO purposes. Why not just change the code to only redirect when NOT a slug is provided, IE:

Change the line:

```
if ($slug) {
```

to

```
if (!$slug) {
```

Then the code won't get trapped in a redirect-loop (as suggested by Ron Dadon) and the posts will always show with the slug in the URL.

I cannot guess any other reason for linking to a post as you do in your question `example.com/blog/1/anything` - why would you want to put `anything` in the URL? This could only be the slug, right?